# Should we retag questions where the new tag is the answer to the question?

Tags: discussion

I'm referring to questions in the format of `"What is...?"`, `"What's the name of...?"` or `"Which application can...?"` where only after the question has been answered you can tag it with the relevant tag, which is basically the answer for the question.

Look at this question, for example: [Is there an official name for Metro-Style apps?](https://superuser.com/questions/496042/is-there-an-official-name-for-metro-style-apps)

It is tagged with [windows-8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8), but not with [windows-store-app](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-store-app), which is what the question is really about - because the OP didn't know that what he was referring to is called "Windows Store apps" when he asked this question.

Should this question be tagged with the [windows-store-app](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-store-app) as well? Is it okay retagging the question now? Should similar questions in this format be retagged as well?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4088/retagging-questions-with-the-answer).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My personal logic is that this should be permitted.

This is because I see tags as classifications, and obviously the above post needs to be
classified under "windows store app". Anyone who follows this tag would probably
want to know about the confusion people are experiencing with Microsoft zigzagging
its way after Apple & Co.

The only other tag possible - "Metro-Style apps" is non-existent and an abomination
besides, so is to be avoided. This would leave the post with only the existing generic
"Windows 8" tag, which is really not very informative.

The right approach should probably be to wait until "windows store app"
is accepted as the answer, though, before adding the tag, as a matter of netiquette.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, obviously. What would the counter argument be?

Comment: Confusion. *"Wait, why did you tag this XYZ – why did you ask if you already know the answer? …… "* This might happen with new users who don't know about editing etc. Not a big argument though.

Comment: @slhck Yes, as the other answer mentions at the end, this should only be done once the answer is accepted, otherwise you'll reduce the number of people looking at a question and "left-field" answers are less likely.

Comment: Wait, that doesn't make sense. Retagging a question around the appropriate answer (eg "windows store app") would surely make the question more visible to answerers with the appropriate expertise - not less.

Comment: @SteveBennett Yes, and it may cause new useful, perhaps even better accepted answers, but, in general, until the OP has signified they accept the _answer_ (#) really is of that category, by accepting an answer, it is bad form to reduce the range of people who will look at the question, even if they're more likely to be the right people. (#) Where the _question_ is truly better tagged, such as if the original question had been tagged only windows, not windows-8, _that_ is a justifiable re-tagging before any particular answer is accepted.